# If clause in mysql select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select

My full query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT vehicle_id,  fuel_type, gearbox_type, door_type, engine_package_name, FORMAT(engine_cap, 1)engine_cap, engine_power, FORMAT(fuel_cons, 1)fuel_cons, FORMAT(std_price, 0)std_price 
FROM vehicle 
WHERE model_id = '$model_id' 
AND fuel_type IN ('$fuel_type1', '$fuel_type2', '$fuel_type3', '$fuel_type4') AND gearbox_type IN( '$gearbox_type1', '$gearbox_type2', '$gearbox_type3', '$gearbox_type4') AND door_type IN ('$door_type1', '$door_type2', '$door_type3', '$door_type4')" ;
```

I would like to skip the part of the query shown below if `$fuel_type1` equals to zero.

```
AND fuel_type IN ('$fuel_type1', '$fuel_type2', '$fuel_type3', '$fuel_type4')
```

I have tried

```
$sql = "SELECT vehicle_id,  fuel_type, gearbox_type, door_type, engine_package_name, FORMAT(engine_cap, 1)engine_cap, engine_power, FORMAT(fuel_cons, 1)fuel_cons, FORMAT(std_price, 0)std_price 
FROM vehicle 
WHERE model_id = '$model_id' ";

if($fuel_type1 != 0) 
{ 
    $sql += “ AND fuel_type IN ('$fuel_type1', '$fuel_type2', '$fuel_type3', '$fuel_type4')”;
}
```

didn't worked.

Also I have tried

```
$sql = "SELECT vehicle_id, fuel_type, gearbox_type, door_type, engine_package_name, FORMAT(engine_cap, 1)engine_cap, engine_power, FORMAT(fuel_cons, 1)fuel_cons, FORMAT(std_price, 0)std_price 
FROM vehicle 
WHERE model_id='$model_id’ 
AND IF($fuel_type1 <> 0,'fuel_type','0') IN ('$fuel_type1', '$fuel_type2', '$fuel_type3', '$fuel_type4’)";
```

didn't worked :((

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the first try should work, what errors did you receive?

Comment: problem is in your concatenation process
in PHP there should b a do t```.``` to concatenate not ```+``` sign
```
if($fuel_type1 != 0) 
{ 
    $sql .= “ AND fuel_type IN ('$fuel_type1', '$fuel_type2', '$fuel_type3', '$fuel_type4')”;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is in your concatenation process

in PHP there should b a do t`.` to concatenate not `+` sign

```
if($fuel_type1 != 0) 
{ 
    $sql .= “ AND fuel_type IN ('$fuel_type1', '$fuel_type2', '$fuel_type3', '$fuel_type4')”;
}
```